# How to fix collapsing toolbar scrolling issue

Tags: android, scrollview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, appbar

I am trying to implement collapsing toolbar which I implement but I am not getting proper output.

when I'll try to scroll using recyclerview item it's not scrolling properly but somehow it's scrolling ok if I'll scroll on touch outside of recyclerview

I am getting this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIKQu.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ctolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsed"
            app:expandedTitleMargin="5dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed|scroll"
            app:title="Profile">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/cover"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_cover" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="100dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flmiddle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_round">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/righteous_regular"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Jack Sparrow"
                            android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvaddress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                            android:text="221 B Baker Street, London"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="3">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Purchased"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/josefinsans_semibold"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:textColor="#ff878b91"
                                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                                    android:text="1.5 K"
                                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                                    android:textSize="24sp"
                                    android:textStyle="normal" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Wished"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/josefinsans_semibold"
                                    android:textColor="#ff878b91"
                                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                                    android:text="1.1 K"
                                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                                    android:textSize="24sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Likes"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/josefinsans_semibold"
                                    android:textColor="#ff878b91"
                                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                                    android:text="450"
                                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                                    android:textSize="24sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgprofile"
                    android:layout_width="68dp"
                    android:layout_height="68dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/righteous_regular"
                    android:text="Collection"
                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewCollection"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/righteous_regular"
                    android:text="Tags"
                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewTags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/righteous_regular"
                    android:text="Offers!!!"
                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="#ff3f4751"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewOffers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help would be highly appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could disable nested scrolling for `RecyclerView` while using it with `NestedScrollView`

```
recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

or to support older versions;

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(this, shouldScroll)
```

Comment: android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" is working for me

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

in RecyclerView properties.

Answer (score 1):

You should try for `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```

and for `Toolbar`

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

Also try to follow [**this**](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout#creating-collapsing-effects), surely it will helps you a lot.